# Working with multiple parameters in CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, database, spring-data-jpa

I have a need to use JpaSpecificationExecutor.
Initially, I assumed that one parameter would be given as input and I would process it like this:

```
List<Car> findCarsByParameters(
            String brand,
            Integer color
    ) {
        Specification<Car> querySpec = new Specification<Car>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                if (!brand.isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("brand"), brand));
                }
                if (color != null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("color"), color));
                }
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }
        };
        return carRepository.findAll(querySpec);
    }
```

CarRepository :

```
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor
```

However, I need to be able to work with:

```
List<String> brands,
List<Integer> colors
```

And in response to me came all the options for suitable machines.

For example input:

```
brand = {honda, toyota},
color = {0x00ffff, 0x800000}
```

At the output, I want to get all the machines whose properties fall under one of the following conditions:

```
{honda,0x00ffff};{honda,0x800000};{toyota,0x00ffff};{toyota,0x800000}
```

How do I need to modify my code so that it works like I gave in the example? Or where can I read about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-and-or-criteria-predicates) perfectly explains what you need.

You basically iterate through the `List<Brand>`, create a list of brand predicates then consider this list as one block of predicate.

```
List<Car> findCarsByParameters(
        List<String> brands,
        List<Integer> colors
) {
    Specification<Car> querySpec = new Specification<Car>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            List<Predicate> brandPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if (brands != null && !brand.isEmpty()) {
                brandPredicates = brands.stream()
                                        .map((brand) -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("brand"), brand))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

            Predicate predicateForBrand = criteriaBuilder.or(brandPredicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
            List<Predicate> colorPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if (colors != null && !colors.isEmpty()) {
                colorPredicates = colors.stream()
                                        .map((color) -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("color"), color))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

            Predicated predicateForColor = criteriaBuilder.or(colorPredicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicateForColor, predicateForBrand);
        }
    };
    return carRepository.findAll(querySpec);
}
```